# Can't log in to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login

Ubuntu installed some updates, and after the restart, I cannot log in.  It seems to accept, but then beeps and returns to the login screen.  All of the users, including guest do the same thing.

I was looking at some other posts here, and tried some of the suggestions without success.  I looked at the .xsession-errors file but I don't understand the error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  34
  Current serial number in output stream:  35
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (1751) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (1737) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: logrotate main process (1601) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_compiz.1001.crash) main process (1669) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_compiz.1002.crash) main process (1671) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (1730) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (1735) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (1795) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (1796) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (1797) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application main process (1844) killed by TERM signal
upstart: job window-stack-bridge failed to stop
```

Thanks,
David

Comment: So to follow up and close this thread out...   The authority edits and folder permissions did not help, I still could not log in.  I also tried updating the nvidia drivers, and removing them via 'sudo nvidia-settings --uninstall' but that did not help either.  What finally did work was totally removing the nvidia drivers     'sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*'     and a restart.   Thanks to @jargonjunkie for the right commands that worked.

Answer (score -2):

Set appropriate ownership to .Xauthority and .ICEauthority.

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
chown username:username .ICEauthority
```

Set permission for /tmp

```
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
```

Restart lightdm

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Reboot and login, this should fix your problem, if not then remove incompatible graphics driver:

For Nvidia:

```
sudo nvidia-settings --uninstall 
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

For amd:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Comment: Please don't go around posting (almost) the same answer to various similar questions! Instead, you should try to flag them as duplicates of the question with the answer that was the source for your answer. If no such question exists, create one such answer yourself and flag the other questions as a duplicate of it.